# Sketch boolean operation: convert to outline for rectangle

Tags: sketch-app

Anyone knows how to "convert to outline" for a rectangle without fill?

Refer to the picture below, if I use "convert to outline" directly on the rectangle, it results in two shapes, the inner one has a funny shape at the four corners.

[image]

What I am looking for is the same effect as in the icons below. I think one possible solution is to cut off a smaller rectangle from a larger rectangle. However, it seems to me that this is not a good way as its getting complicated if the lines within the rectangle forms a complicated pattern.

[image]
How do you solve the problem? There is a similar question but not answered yet. 
[Problem with boolean operations in Sketch 3.6.1](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/68132/problem-with-boolean-operations-in-sketch-3-6-1)